# How to get distinct combination of groups

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have a table like

```
name_id     disease_id   
-------     ----------    
1           1    
1           2    
2           2    
3           1    
3           3    
4           1    
4           2    
5           2
```

I need to find the distinct combination of disease_id across the entire table. I can't group by name_id because that would yield non distinct combinations (see name_id 1 and 4).  I can't omit GROUP BY that would yield a simple list of disease_id across all name_id.

What I want to be able to answer is a question like: What are the distinct combinations of childhood diseases that occurred within a population (and later on perhaps adding a count:

```
Chickenpox          (10)
Chickenpox+Measles  (2)
Measles             (5)
Measles+Mumps       (1)
etc.
```

Comment: as per my understanding,in the table provided all are distinct combinations  ?,right ..and also your requirement is not clear.please look here to know how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Would you please show us the desired output too? Your problem is not clear enough for me, at least!

Comment: Name_id 1 and 4 have same disease_id (1,2). Name_id 2 and 5 have same disease_id (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has two steps.

1. Enumerate set of diseases each patient suffering from; store it in a separate table
2. Use above table to list distinct combination of diseases as well as count of patients suffering from those combinations.

Now, for the step #1 you require a stored procedure which goes as under:

```
DECLARE @prv int
DECLARE @nid int
DECLARE @dname varchar(100)
DECLARE @combi varchar(500)

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT name_id, disease_name 
FROM patients 
JOIN diseases ON patients.disease_id = diseases.disease_id
ORDER BY name_id, disease_name;

DELETE FROM diseasecombi;

OPEN c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @nid, @dname 
SET @prv = @nid
SET @combi = ''

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @prv <> @nid
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO diseasecombi (name_id, suffers) VALUES (@prv, @combi)
        SET @prv = @nid
        SET @combi = ''
    END
    IF LEN(@combi) > 0 SET @combi = @combi + ', '
    SET @combi = @combi + @dname
    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @nid, @dname
END
INSERT INTO diseasecombi(name_id, suffers) VALUES (@prv, @combi)

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

The stored procedure above will produce a table which will look like

```
name_id suffers
------- -------------------------------
1       Chickenpox, Mumps
2       Chickenpox, Fibroids, Measles
3       Chickenpox, Mumps
4       Chickenpox, Measles
5       Chickenpox, Measles
6       Chickenpox
7       Rashes
```

For step #2, the query is as under:

```
SELECT suffers, COUNT(*) AS Patients 
FROM diseasecombi
GROUP BY suffers
ORDER BY suffers
```

Which produces output as under:

```
Diseases                        Patients
------------------------------  ----------
Chickenpox                      1
Chickenpox, Fibroids, Measles   1
Chickenpox, Measles             2
Chickenpox, Mumps               2
Rashes                          1
```

Comment: Is the stored procedure supposed to create table 'diseasecombi'?

Comment: table 'diseasecombi' has two columns: name_id (int) and suffers (varchar(MAX)). The table is just used by the stored procedure, supposed to exists before stored procedure is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to answer a question like "What are the distinct combinations of childhood diseases that occurred within a population".

My answer is based on following assumptions:

1. disease_id refers to Chickenpox, Measles, Mumps etc
2. name_id refers to patient
3. disease_id 1 refers to 'Chickenpox' and disease_id 3 refers 'Measles'; and both are considered childhood diseases. (This is just for example, yours can be different)

Based on above assumption, query below produces the desired result:

```
SELECT 'Chickenpox' as 'DiseaseName', COUNT(*) as 'Patients' 
FROM (
    SELECT name_id FROM table GROUP BY name_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 WHERE disease_id  = 1
    ) d1
UNION 
SELECT 'Measles' as 'DiseaseName', COUNT(*) as 'Patients' 
FROM (
    SELECT name_id FROM table GROUP BY name_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 WHERE disease_id = 3
    ) d3
UNION
SELECT 'Chickenpox + Measles' as 'DiseaseName', COUNT(*) as 'Patients' 
FROM (
    SELECT name_id FROM table GROUP BY name_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 WHERE disease_id IN (1,3) 
    ) d1d3
```

Result will be as under:

```
DiseaseName           Patients
--------------------  ---------
Chickenpox            10
Measles               5
Chickenpox+Measels    2
```

Comment: That's the right idea. How did you come up with the distinct combinations? By looking at the data, right? Imagine there are millions of rows. How would you find the distinct combinations in that case? I need the query to find them.

Comment: @user2378895, How many diseases (not combinations but only disease) do you have? And for example, how do you decide which set of diseases are considered 'Childhood Disease' and set of diseases for another group and so on?